# Azure function multiple output binding Extensions error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I'm developing an Azure function through the portal,

My function is an HttpTrigger with httpResponse.

I add a TableStorage output binding and install its Extension (everything is fine).

I add a SendGrid output binding and install its Extension (the extension installer give me a message saying "it takes longer than expected" and seems to fail.  Afterward, my function is broken.

I tried creating my bindings in reverse order (SendGrid then TableStorage).  It now fails on TableStorage installation.

Any way to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/132) that sometimes filesystem for Consumption plans reacts slow, e.g during extension installation with many file I/O operations.

The first suggestion is to delete the extensions and retry.

1. Stop Function app.
2. In portal, Platform features> App Service Editor.
3. Right click on `bin` folder and `extensions.csproj`, Delete.
4. Start Function app.
5. Delete existing output bindings and add them again to install extensions.

If this doesn't work, try to manually install the extensions.

1. Stop Function app.
2. In portal, Platform features> App Service Editor.
3. Right clik on the blank under `WWWROOT`, New File `extensions.csproj` then add content below.

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
       <WarningsAsErrors />
     </PropertyGroup>
     <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid" Version="3.0.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.2" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.0.*" />
     </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
4. Press `Ctrl+Shift+C` to open console, or click the second button `Open Console` from the bottom on the sidebar.
5. Input `dotnet build extensions.csproj -o bin --no-incremental --packages D:\home\.nuget` and wait for the command to finish.
6. Start Function app.

Comment: Hey @Jerry, thanks but that did not work at the time I tried it.  I ended up building my fucntions in Visual Studio.

Comment: @danbord Glad to hear you have moved on. It's a better solution if we could choose pre-compiled code.

Comment: Yes, I still find that Azure functions are an amazing tool!  But for more complex development its clearly a better idea to do it within a development tool :)